# Efficiently find value in different DataFrame for each row

Tags: r, query-optimization, apply

I have a DataFrame `df` that looks like this:

| Text | Part | SToken |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | P03 | abandoned |
| 3 | P08 | about |
| 3 | P01 | StackOverflow |
| 3 | P02 | academy |
| 3 | P04 | across |

I have another, large DataFrame with frequency counts called `freq` that looks like this.

| SToken | Log_Freq_HAL | LgSUBTLWF | Concreteness_Rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 16.177 | 6.018 | 1.46 |
| abandoned | 8.549 | 2.832 | 2.52 |
| ability | 10.949 | 2.992 | 1.81 |
| about | 14.083 | 5.268 | 1.77 |
| absent | 8.013 | 2.121 | 2.7 |

I want to add a col `Log_Freq_HAL` to `df` so that the correct `Log_Freq_HAL` is given for each `SToken` in `df`. If an `SToken` is not in `freq`, than `1` should be given. (But filling NAs in `df` is not possible at it does contain other NAs.)

So the resulting Data Frame would look like this:

| Text | Part | SToken | Log_Freq_HAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | P03 | abandoned | 8.549 |
| 3 | P08 | about | 14.083 |
| 3 | P01 | StackOverflow | 1 |
| 3 | P02 | absent | 8.013 |
| 3 | P04 | ability | 10.949 |

I'm looking for an efficient solution as the frequency table and the dataset are both quite large. I tried using `apply` but got stuck along the way. In the snippet below I'd use a lambda function in Python, but I am not sure how to handle this in R.

```
df$Log_Freq_HAL<-apply(df, 1, FUNC)
```

Comment: I think you're looking to do a join. There's `merge` in base, `left_join` in `dplyr`, or you can use `data.table`.

Comment: Are the values 'absent' and 'ability' in `df$SToken`?
In other words, are you expecting a left join or an full join?

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez No, it is not guaranteed that all words in `freq$SToken` are somewhere in `df$SToken`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my proposal, but without a large enough dataset to test it, I can not compare its efficiency to other methods.

It relies on data.table package to both store/index and join the dfs. data.table is known to be more efficient than base and tidyverse's tibble for such tasks.
But it relies on tidyverse's `dplyr::if_else()` to mutate Log_Freq_HAL if `df$SToken` exists in `freq$SToken` and return a 1 if it does not. `if_else` should be 'somewhat' faster than base `ifelse`.

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
    
df  <- as.data.table(df)
freq  <- as.data.table(freq)

merged_df <-
  merge(x = df, y = freq[,c("SToken", "Log_Freq_HAL")], 
        all.x = TRUE, by = "SToken") %>% 
  mutate(Log_Freq_HAL = if_else(SToken %in% freq$SToken, 
                                true = Log_Freq_HAL, 
                                false = 1)) %>% 
  select(Text, Part, SToken, Log_Freq_HAL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
transform(
  df,
  Log_Freq_HAL = replace(freq$Log_Freq_HAL[idx <- match(freq$SToken, SToken)], is.na(idx), 1)
)
```

which gives

```
  Text Part        SToken Log_Freq_HAL
1    3  P03     abandoned        1.000
2    3  P08         about       16.177
3    3  P01 StackOverflow        1.000
4    3  P02       academy        8.549
5    3  P04        across        1.000
```

Comment: No, this does not correspond to my example and expected result.